# Populating a pie chart with mysql field values

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to create,populate a pie chart in php with mysql column values?

I have a column called subject that contains 40 or so different values and I would like to create a pie chart and display the top 10 values. I have tried with rgraph but can not get it to work at all, are there solutions that are easier to set up out there?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ORDER BY to sort the column by values and retrieve them from your database then a for loop in PHP to take the first ten and save them to an array. You can then populate a javascript pie chart from your array.